# How to create a single threaded singleton in Rust?

Tags: rust, concurrency, ffi

I'm currently trying to wrap a C library in rust that has a few requirements. The C library can only be run on a single thread, and can only be initialized / cleaned up once on the same thread. I want something something like the following.

```
extern "C" {
    fn init_lib() -> *mut c_void;
    fn cleanup_lib(ctx: *mut c_void);
}

// This line doesn't work.
static mut CTX: Option<(ThreadId, Rc<Context>)> = None;

struct Context(*mut c_void);

impl Context {
    fn acquire() -> Result<Rc<Context>, Error> {
        // If CTX has a reference on the current thread, clone and return it.
        // Otherwise initialize the library and set CTX.
    }
}

impl Drop for Context {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { cleanup_lib(self.0); }
    }
}
```

Anyone have a good way to achieve something like this? Every solution I try to come up with involves creating a Mutex / Arc and making the `Context` type `Send` and `Sync` which I don't want as I want it to remain single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution I came up with was to just implement the reference counting myself, removing the need for `Rc` entirely.

```
#![feature(once_cell)]

use std::{error::Error, ffi::c_void, fmt, lazy::SyncLazy, sync::Mutex, thread::ThreadId};

extern "C" {
    fn init_lib() -> *mut c_void;
    fn cleanup_lib(ctx: *mut c_void);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ContextError {
    InitOnOtherThread,
}

impl fmt::Display for ContextError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            ContextError::InitOnOtherThread => {
                write!(f, "Context already initialized on a different thread")
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Error for ContextError {}

struct StaticPtr(*mut c_void);
unsafe impl Send for StaticPtr {}

static CTX: SyncLazy<Mutex<Option<(ThreadId, usize, StaticPtr)>>> =
    SyncLazy::new(|| Mutex::new(None));

pub struct Context(*mut c_void);

impl Context {
    pub fn acquire() -> Result<Context, ContextError> {
        let mut ctx = CTX.lock().unwrap();
        if let Some((id, ref_count, ptr)) = ctx.as_mut() {
            if *id == std::thread::current().id() {
                *ref_count += 1;
                return Ok(Context(ptr.0));
            }

            Err(ContextError::InitOnOtherThread)
        } else {
            let ptr = unsafe { init_lib() };
            *ctx = Some((std::thread::current().id(), 1, StaticPtr(ptr)));
            Ok(Context(ptr))
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Context {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut ctx = CTX.lock().unwrap();
        let (_, ref_count, ptr) = ctx.as_mut().unwrap();
        *ref_count -= 1;
        if *ref_count == 0 {
            unsafe {
                cleanup_lib(ptr.0);
            }
            *ctx = None;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code ensures that a Context can only be acquired in the special thread, but it doesn't prevent it from being used re-entrantly (overlapping calls in other threads).

Comment: Since the mutex is locked, wouldn't that trigger the Err case?

Comment: Once the Context is created by `acquire()`, the caller can do anything it wants to with it, including pass it to other threads.

Comment: Since `Context` holds a raw pointer, it is both `!Sync` and `!Send`, so it can't be used on multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most 'rustic' way to do this is with [`std::sync::mpsc::sync_channel`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.sync_channel.html) and an enum describing library operations.

The only public-facing elements of this module are `launch_lib()`, the `SafeLibRef` struct (but not its internals), and the `pub fn` that are part of the `impl SafeLibRef`.

Also, this example strongly represents the philosophy that the best way to deal with global state is to not have any.

I have played fast and loose with the `Result::unwrap()` calls.  It would be more responsible to handle error conditions better.

```
use std::sync::{ atomic::{ AtomicBool, Ordering }, mpsc::{ SyncSender, Receiver, sync_channel } };
use std::ffi::c_void;

extern "C" {
    fn init_lib() -> *mut c_void;
    fn do_op_1(ctx: *mut c_void, a: u16, b: u32, c: u64) -> f64;
    fn do_op_2(ctx: *mut c_void, a: f64) -> bool;
    fn cleanup_lib(ctx: *mut c_void);
}

enum LibOperation {
    Op1(u16,u32,u64,SyncSender<f64>),
    Op2(f64, SyncSender<bool>),
    Terminate(SyncSender<()>),
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct SafeLibRef(SyncSender<LibOperation>);

fn lib_thread(rx: Receiver<LibOperation>) {

    static  LIB_INITIALIZED: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);
    
    if LIB_INITIALIZED.compare_exchange(false, true, Ordering::SeqCst, Ordering::SeqCst).is_err() {
        panic!("Tried to double-initialize library!");
    }
    
    let libptr = unsafe { init_lib() };
    loop {
        let op = rx.recv();
        if op.is_err() {
            unsafe { cleanup_lib(libptr) };
            break;
        }
        match op.unwrap() {
            LibOperation::Op1(a,b,c,tx_res) => {
                let res: f64 = unsafe { do_op_1(libptr, a, b, c) };
                tx_res.send(res).unwrap();
            },
            LibOperation::Op2(a, tx_res) => {
                let res: bool = unsafe { do_op_2(libptr, a) };
                tx_res.send(res).unwrap();
            }
            LibOperation::Terminate(tx_res) => {
                unsafe { cleanup_lib(libptr) };
                tx_res.send(()).unwrap();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/// This needs to be called no more than once.
/// The resulting SafeLibRef can be cloned and passed around.
pub fn launch_lib() -> SafeLibRef {
    let (tx,rx) = sync_channel(0);
    std::thread::spawn(|| lib_thread(rx));
    SafeLibRef(tx)
}

// This is the interface that most of your code will use
impl SafeLibRef {
    
    pub fn  op_1(&self, a: u16, b: u32, c: u64) -> f64 {
        let (res_tx, res_rx) = sync_channel(1);
        self.0.send(LibOperation::Op1(a, b, c, res_tx)).unwrap();
        res_rx.recv().unwrap()
    }
    pub fn  op_2(&self, a: f64) -> bool {
        let (res_tx, res_rx) = sync_channel(1);
        self.0.send(LibOperation::Op2(a, res_tx)).unwrap();
        res_rx.recv().unwrap()
    }
    pub fn terminate(&self) {
        let (res_tx, res_rx) = sync_channel(1);
        self.0.send(LibOperation::Terminate(res_tx)).unwrap();
        res_rx.recv().unwrap();
    }
}
```